# node.js cron command not executed

Tags: cron

Nothing appears in the console window.
But the command that should be executed every second is not executed.
This is my code.

```js
const cron = require('cron');

new cron.CronJob('* * * * * *', () => {
  console.log("Execute")
},
  null, true, "Asia/Seoul"
).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to define a cronjob into a const like

```js
const job = new cron.Cronjob()
```

Btw. you don't need to call the `start()` method if you set the fourth argument to true.

Comment: Your code is working fine in my test environment. Seems to be another issue.